# How to make a word in a Titanium TextArea bold or italic

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

Is it possible to format the text in a Titanium TextArea (or similar?) to make some words bold some italic, etc.?

I am trying to display a paragraph of text in my Titanium Alloy app but can't see any way to have some words bold and some italic.

It may be that TextArea is not the right thing to be using? I am just wanting to display a simple paragraph of word wrapped text where some of the words are formatted.

Comment: not in a textarea, try using `contenteditable` element

Comment: That does not appear to be a Titanium Alloy element.

Comment: it's an html property

Comment: Can you use html in Titanium Alloy? How does that work?

Comment: Have you tried `Titanium.UI.iOS.AttributedString` http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.AttributedString

Comment: I hadn't come across AttributedString before so thanks for pointing it out Swanand. It looks like it only works for iOS which is sad, but it also seems a very clunky way of doing things. I am surprised there is not something akin to HTML markup that can be used.

Comment: You can use a webView to add html markup http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView

Comment: Thanks pete80 that looks as if it will be the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a Label (`Ti.UI.Label`) is what you need. It can hold multiple lines and can support HTML tags thank's to Fokke Zandbergen's module or widget  [ti-html2as](https://github.com/FokkeZB/ti-html2as). It provide HTML tags like **bold**(`<b>bold</b>`) *italic* and so on and it works for both android and ios. The module or the widget are well documented so give it a try...

Comment: Thanks Coyote that is exactly the answer I was hoping for.